# How to use offset for start and end in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a row that contains a text, an icon and a text:

```
Row {
    Text(text = "I")
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Text(text = "you")
}
```

I need to write "I ❤️ you". What I need is to cut the space from the start and the end of the icon to look like this "I❤️you". So I tried to use an offset:

```
Row {
    Text(text = "I")
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = (-12).dp
        ),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Text(text = "you")
}
```

But I only could cut 12 dp from the beginning. How to cut as well from the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `offset` you won't be able to change size of item or remove it's padding – "cut the space". Offset is just placing item depending on provided value (in your case in X axis by `-12dp`). So it's not the best `Modifier` for your purposes.

However, it could be achieved using `offset`, take a look at this:

```
Row {
    Text(text = "I")
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(x = (-2).dp),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(x = (-4).dp),
        text = "you",
    )
}
```

First we offset the icon to the left to align with the `Text` "I", then we offset the `Text` "you" to align with a heart.

Like you can see it could be done using `offset` but I would suggest to experiment with other modifiers, I think that it could be achieved in simpler way.

You could also just use the simplest solution and use heart in `Text`, like this:

```
Text(text = "I❤️you")
```

It's possible to use emoji in `Text`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try tomorrow and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change how the `Icon` is measured by using [`layout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).layout(kotlin.Function3)) modifier.

```
Row {
    Text(text = "I")
    // How much space you want to remove from the start and the end of the Icon
    val offsetDp = 2.dp
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    // Offset in pixels
    val offsetPx = remember(offsetDp) { density.run { offsetDp.roundToPx() } }
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                layout(placeable.width - offsetPx * 2, placeable.height) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(-offsetPx, 0)
                }
            },
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Text(
        text = "you",
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try tomorrow and I'll get back to you.